# Convert python lists using numpy lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Given that (Python 2.7):

```
import numpy as np

mylist = []
for i in range(5):
    r = np.random.rand(2)
    mylist.append(r)
print(mylist)
```

I want to use `numpy` instead of `mylist`. In other words, I want to previous code to use `numpy` lists.

Comment: `np.random.rand(5,2)`?

Comment: Is your focus on getting many random numbers or on creating an array by iteration?  If the latter, just use `np.array(mylist)` at the end.  For iteration, lists are better.